# wpf c# DispatcherUnhandledException not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling, .net-4.0

I am in the process of creating a new WPF application and wanted to implement the DispatcherUnhandledException handler.

My application is using a custom [STAThread] to handle the application startup rather than the App.XAML

As you can see I register the handler in the Main() method:

```
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
       var application = new App();
       application.DispatcherUnhandledException += application_DispatcherUnhandledException;
       application.Run();

    }
```

With the associated method:

```
static void application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

When ever I throw an exception anywhere in the code it is picked up by the VS2013 debugger rather than being handled in the UI.

```
throw new Exception("TEST");
```

Can anyone suggest what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the VS feature to catch user-unhandled exception. You can turn it off by going to

> Debug -> Exceptions

and then unchecking user-unhandled CLR expections.

On the other hand if you don't want to do that, just hit F5 when debugger shows you exception and you will get your breakpoint hit.